# Take substring from dictionary value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, substring

I have a dictionary containing variables and their values.

This is my dictionary, for example:

```
{27: 'choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4): ")',
 31: 'num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))',
 32: 'num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))',
 48: 'next_calculation = input("Let\'s do next calculation? (yes/no): ")'}
```

and I want to go over values in the dictionary and save a substring of the string in the list.

The output should look like this from the previous dict:

```
list = ['choice','num1','num2','next_calculation']
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension. Assuming `d` the input dictionary.

```
lst = [x.split()[0] for x in d.values()]
```

output: `['choice', 'num1', 'num2', 'next_calculation']`

*NB. do not name your variable `list`, this is a python builtin*

If you have a very long string or want to explicitly define a different separator, use:

```
lst = [x.split(sep=' = ', maxsplit=1)[0] for x in d.values()]
```